# How to have same behaviour of OutputStream compared to PrintWriter

Tags: java, sockets, nio

I have some code which opens a socket and sends data via PrintWriter.write() & flush. This works in such a way that the server response with an error saying "I did not receive correct XML".

I was using the PrintWriter for that, but now I want to go even more "lowlevel" and use the OutputStream directly because I have to send a correct byte array, with special header bytes, etc., and I suspect the PrintWriter is doing some conversions internally that I do not want.

My code before:

```
var out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
var buffer = packData(msg, count); //constructing the special byteArr
out.print(new String(buffer.array()));
out.flush();
```

This prompts the server to respond with the error message.

Now, if I transform that to use the OutputStream directly, I don't get any response from the server, which means the server is still waiting for more:

```
var out = socket.getOutputStream();
var buffer = packData(msg, count); //constructing the special byteArr
out.write(buffer.array());
out.flush();
```

What is the fundamental difference between these two code pieces? Why is the first one working and the second one not?

Comment: Any `Writer` takes `String` (or string-like) input and a `OutputStream` takes `byte[]` (or byte stream-like) input. That is the fundamental difference. If you want to send fixed bytes that you constructed somehow, then trying to do that with a `PrintWriter` is fundamentally flawed. While you might be able to achieve that in some roundabout way, that code will be very fragile and hard to read. If you plan to send bytes, use a `OutputStream`.

Comment: Please read the last question. I tried to convert to outputstream, but i dont understand why there is a difference. What do i need to do to make the second code work?

Comment: You can't convert arbitrary non-text bytes into string and expect that conversion to "just work". That's what encodings are for. If your data is fundamentally not text (or it is text, but you don't provide the correct encoding when converting it to/from `String`), then the conversion will at best be lossy and often just flat out wrong. At the very least each point where you convert between `String` and `byte[]` (or create a `Writer` over a `OutputStream`) **must** define which encoding to use to work reliably.

Comment: *This works in such a way that the server response with an error saying "I did not receive correct XML".* It must be said that it's probably quite rare for a protocol to combine XML and 'binary data' so using `OutputStream` directly might be inappropriate. We can't tell without knowing details of your protocol